Catch connecting second monitor
On Windows and MacOs, is there a message that is sent when an external monitor is attached?
The problem comes from a scenario when I start my program on a local monitor, exit, then attach a second monitor and make it a first one.
Or vice versa - start the app on an external monitor, close it then remove the monitor, and start the program on a local monitor (with less size/DPI).

Both of your scenarios involve your app not running when the monitor is changed. So a message wouldn't help you. Seems like you just need to retrieve the current monitor config when your app starts up before displaying any UI on any monitor

you have winapi and cocoa tagged ... pick one

@AhmedAEK, why? I need solution for both. Or you suggesting to create absolutely identical post for 2 OSes? But I will not be able to...

@RemyLebeau, thx I was thinking the same, but wanted to make sure there is no other way...

@Igor your question only makes sense if you want to detect the 2nd monitor being (dis)connected while your app is running. I don't know about MacOs, but Windows does have such a message - WM_DEVICECHANGE. See Device notifications

About Windows:
As Remy said. You could try to use WM_DEVICECHANGE message. The message notifies an application of a change to the hardware configuration of a device or the computer. For more details you could refer to the Doc:Device Notifications.
About MacOS:
You could try to use the notification NSApplication.didChangeScreenParametersNotification
You could refer to the thread:Detect when a new display is connected on macOS
